# files in SVN in a given date

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

Im trying to checkout the content of a SVN repository in a given date. The most i could do is to get the files commited in that given date. Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
svn co -r {2015-01-03} https://path-to-your-repo
```

Note that this will checkout files until 1 date before date specified (2015-01-02 in this case): [Is Subversion a Day Early?](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html)

Comment: A better way to state it is "Subversion will check out the repository state as of the beginning of the specified date."